# Firefox version not the newest

Tags: release-loki, appcenter, firefox

Why doesn't the AppCenter download the latest version of Firefox 49.0.1?  Is there a way to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu maintains [the Firefox package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/firefox) that elementary OS uses (both in `apt install` and in the AppCenter). Ubuntu is [pretty good](https://askubuntu.com/q/6339/49899) at keeping it up to date.

In this case [49.0.1](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/49.0.1/releasenotes/) is only an update for Windows, so it shouldn't be of much importance. But you can [download the binary](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and install it over your old release if you want.